# 'Location enable permission' alert disappear after few second(3 to 4 second) in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using 'react-native-geolocation-service' library for enabling the location for the app, if location is disabled. So if location is disabled then permission alert is working fine in android but In IOS it is appear for few second like 2 or 3 second, after that it will close. Below is the sample of method.

```
static hasLocationPermissionIOS = async () => {
    const status = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('always');

    if (status === 'granted') {
      return 'GRANTED';
    }

    if (status === 'denied') {
      return 'DENIED';
    }

    if (status === 'disabled') {
      return 'DISABLED';
    }
  };
  static hasLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');
      const hasPermission = await this.hasLocationPermissionIOS();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const hasPermission = await this.hasLocationPermissionAndroid();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    return false;
  };

 static hasLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');
      const hasPermission = await this.hasLocationPermissionIOS();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const hasPermission = await this.hasLocationPermissionAndroid();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    return false;
  };

static getLocation = async () => {
    const hasLocationPermission = await this.hasLocationPermission();
    if (!hasLocationPermission) {
      return;
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject = (error) => {}) => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=> {
        resolve(position);
      }, (error)=>{
        resolve(error);
      }, {
        accuracy: {
          android: 'high',
          ios: 'best',
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
        showLocationDialog: true,
      });
    });
  };
```

I referred the link but not able to find solution,

> https://github.com/douglasjunior/react-native-get-location/issues/18

Thanks in advance!!!